# Generating Core File on Segmentation Fault

Tags: ros, ubuntu

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
ROS2 Distro: Humble
[image]

I ran a ROS node using ros2 run, but the process crashed with the above error message.

I want to exaime the core file for this error, but I cannot tell if this error is even generating a core file (it doesn't have the "core dumped" message) and where to find the core file.

I typed these following commands into the terminal before running the ROS node

```
ulimit -c unlimited
 $ echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid ...
```

as suggested by this tutorial: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ros-programming-building/9781788627436/fa252378-8d64-4c42-ad20-e8a5374549a5.xhtml

I didn't restart the terminal before running the ros node since "ulimit -c unlimited" resets to 0 on a new terminal.

I tried generating a core dump from a regular C++ program (compiled with g++ and ran by ./name_of_executable). For this case, I saw the "core dumped" message
[image]

and the core file was found in /var/lib/apport/coredump

Is there something I missed, such as a CMake configuration, that is preventing the core file from being generated when the ROS node crashes?

If in the case the core file is already being generated, where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for - but the Nav2 project has some documentation on [Getting Backtraces in ROS 2](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/get_backtrace.html) that might be helpful.